# Can't resolve IDs in xml

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I'm trying to get a `RelativeLayout` up and running, so I can use it for a custom list,
but when I try to space the items compared to eachother it screws up and says:

> Couldn't resolve resource @id/itemName
> Couldn't resolve resource @id/textPriceFrom

This is weird because `textPriceFrom` places itself correctly, but the price doesn't.

Here is code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:text="A good day"
        android:textSize="23dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPriceFrom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemName"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:text="@string/frapris"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPrice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textPriceFrom"
        android:text="145,95"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` made no room for a left/right off which apparently made that error.

Comment: Wow - I'd have thought that would just have made the left/right views not visible, not cause an error

Comment: me too :-) but that was it, when I changed it, it worked without problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `@+id/textPriceFrom` instead of  `@id/textPriceFrom`.

i am really sorry I cudn't explain the reason. But this is how it works for me.

Comment: I think you only add + when you're creating a new id, not referring to an existing one.

Comment: No idea why you would post that as an answer tbh ;-)
Could you try and c/p it and check if it works on ur machine?